# Ajax unable to parse JSON data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I know there are many questions out there on the same topic and I've read all of them but they don't help my case.

I am trying to parse some JSON data returned from my serverside PHP script. I've used JSONLint to verify that the PHP output is a valid JSON string.

I have the following ajax code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#update-stats-submit').on("click", function(){
            if (requestRunning) { // don't do anything if an AJAX request is pending
                return;
            }
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "calculate.php",
                data: "q="+$("#table-info").val(),
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data){
                    $("#update-result").animate({ opacity: 100 });
                    $("#update-result").html(data.output_msg);
                    $("#update-result").delay(3000).animate({ opacity: 0 });
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        $("#update-result").empty();
                    }, 4000);
                    alert(data.avg + "\n" + data.var + "\n" + data.count + "\n" + data.est + "\n" + data.min + "\n" + data.max);
                },
                error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                    $("#update-result").html(xhr.responseText + "\n" + xhr.status + "\n" + thrownError);
                }
            })
            return false;
        });
    });
```

I've not gotten this piece of code to execute successfully. Each time the following error is returned.

```
200 SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
```

Sample JSON output returned from calculate.php:

```
{
"output_msg":"Success!",
"avg":5.79916666667,
"var":4.63505345486,
"n":40,
"est":"1",
"min":"3",
"max":"4"
}
```

Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [json parsing error syntax error unexpected end of input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20827372/json-parsing-error-syntax-error-unexpected-end-of-input)

Comment: pretty certain is not a duplicate

Comment: What is the Response supposed to be? What do you get when you type the url directly in the browser?

Comment: Which line causes the error?

Comment: `"q="+$("#table-info").val(),` should really be `{q:$("#table-info").val()},` so it gets encoded correctly. If not, you should be using encodeURIComponent()

Comment: Error is likely coming from the JSON output in calculate.php. Have you checked how you are encoding the output string from that script?

Comment: @epascarello data is not of JSON type. That's a GET request to be sent to the server.

Comment: @revvy It does not send up JSON!!!.

Comment: Change the code to `... dataType: "text", success: function(data){ console.log(escape(data)); }, ...` what does it output? My guess is there is something in the response that you are not seeing.

Comment: make url as "calculate.php?q="+$("#table-info").val(), remove data from ajax call

Comment: @pankajparkar That will make zero difference.

Comment: When json is returned, it is returned as an array, you cannot simply use data as _data_ .... change it to _data[0]_

Comment: and by the way what is your line number 200 ?

Comment: @epascarello apologies if I have not made myself clear but the it never gets to 'success'. It always returns the error message as per my post above. If i changed dataType to text, then I get the alert box with multiple rows of 'undefined'.

Comment: @pankajparkar that made no difference.

Comment: @bayblade567 200 is the error status. not a line.

Comment: Because the JSON.parse internally is failing so it triggers the error. Switching it to text will make it easier to debug.

Comment: 200 is a **success** code, not an error code, generally... is your server OK?

Comment: @epascarello i tried switching to text. i include var obj = JSON.parse(data) and alert(obj.avg) in the success function; but now there's no error msg and also no alert.

Comment: try changing `data.avg` to `data[0]` and `data.var` to `data[1]` and so on..

Comment: What did the console line show that I told you to try????

Comment: @bayblade567 doesn't work still

Comment: @epascarello its blank

Comment: So the server is not returning anything? Do you see that when you inspect the Ajax request in the console?

Comment: fixed it. there was an if code on the server that led to an exit().

Comment: @epascarello caused some GET requests to output null instead of the JSON string. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Basically there's nothing wrong with the above ajax script. It appears the bug lied with the serverside PHP code that allowed the script to exit() under certain GET request conditions.