# Javascript: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input

Tags: javascript

I'm learning javascript and how to get information from an API and want to do a simple app where user can choose a team and information about players is displayed. When I click the search button, I get `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input`. I have been through the code many times but I do not spot the error. Otherwise the code displays the information I am asking for. It looks like the error is in process_player and searchPlayer.

Jslint shows two warnings but none of them is, I think, related to the problem:

```
Unexpected 'for'.
  for(var i = 0; i < teams.length; i++) {
Unexpected 'var'.
  for(var i = 0; i < teams.length; i++) {
```

Can somebody please explain what I'm doing wrong here?

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <title>Football statistic</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="input">
    <form>
      <select id="myteam">
        <option>Select your team</option>
      </select>
      <input type="button" id="search_button" value="Search">
    </form>
  </div>

    <div id="output"></div>

    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

js code:

```
var teams = [];
function find_team(team_code) {
  for(var i = 0; i < teams.length; i++) {
    if(teams[i].code === team_code) {
      return teams[i];
    }
  }
  return undefined;
}

var process_form = function(team_code) {
    var team = find_team(team_code);
    var player_link = team._links.players;
    player = player_link.href;
};

// write new function to process player
var process_player = function() {
  var data = JSON.parse(xhttp2.response);
  var item = data.players;
  for (var i = 0; i<item.length; i++) {
    person = item[i];
    name = person.name;
    value = person.marketValue;
    country = person.nationality;
    position = person.position;
    processFormPlayer(name);
    processFormPlayer(value);
    processFormPlayer(country);
    processFormPlayer(position);
  };
}

var processFormPlayer = function(text) {
  body = document.getElementById("output");
  var add = document.createTextNode(text);
  var paragraph = document.createElement("p");
  paragraph.appendChild(add);
  body.appendChild(paragraph);
}

var processXHRResponse = function() {
  var data = JSON.parse(xhttp.response);
  teams = data.teams;
  for (var i = 0; i < teams.length; i++) {
    team = teams[i];
    name = team.name;
    dropdownElement = document.createTextNode(name);
    option = document.createElement("option");
    option.value = team.code;
    option.appendChild(dropdownElement);
    document.getElementById("myteam").appendChild(option);
  };
}

var encodeParameters = function(params) {
    var strArray = [];
    for(var key in params) {
        if(params.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            var paramString = encodeURIComponent(key) + "/" + encodeURIComponent(params[key]);
            strArray.push(paramString);
        }
    }
    return strArray.join("&");
}

// the parameters for the API request
var parameters = {
    competitions: 426,
}

// auth Token obtainable from http://api.football-data.org/register
var authToken = "2fe40f6ab37b43cca925d6fac9b05a0e";

// do the XHR request
var base_url = "http://api.football-data.org/v1/";
var query_url = base_url + encodeParameters(parameters) + "/" + "teams";
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.addEventListener("load", processXHRResponse);
xhttp.open("GET", query_url);
xhttp.setRequestHeader("X-Auth-Token", authToken);
xhttp.send();

var doSearch = function () {
  var search_term = document.getElementById("myteam").value;
  process_form(search_term);
}

var searchPlayer = function() {
  xhttp2 = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp2.addEventListener("load", process_player);
  xhttp2.open("GET", player);
  xhttp2.setRequestHeader("X-Auth-Token", authToken);
  xhttp2.send();
  process_player();
}

window.onload = function() {
    var search_button = document.getElementById("search_button");
    search_button.addEventListener("click", doSearch);
    search_button.addEventListener("click", searchPlayer);
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: add `console.log(xhttp.response)` before `JSON.parse`

Comment: It's saying "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input" because you asked it to parse JSON that ended before it was syntactically valid for it to do so. Since you haven't shown us the JSON, we can't really help you understand why.

Comment: JSON.parse will also throw an exception for an empty string

Comment: Why do you `return` within `for` loop?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [json parsing error syntax error unexpected end of input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20827372/json-parsing-error-syntax-error-unexpected-end-of-input)

Comment: You call `process_player()` too early. Give a chance to it to complete request!

Comment: doesn't the process_player functions run before the xhttp2 even finishes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var searchPlayer = function() {
  xhttp2 = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp2.addEventListener("load", process_player);
  xhttp2.open("GET", player);
  xhttp2.setRequestHeader("X-Auth-Token", authToken);
  xhttp2.send();
  //process_player();//you already attached this function as a listener
}
```

Comment: I think there are still some errors with api response. Other way this error has been ignored easily :)

Comment: It works, there are not any errors left, thanks. And sorry for posting, it was pretty obvious.