# PHP SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm building an App with `React` and `Mobx` which gets served data as `JSON` from an `PHP`/`MySQL` backend. The `MySQL`-table until now contained only simple `varchar`-fields and so far it worked ok. Now I added a `Date`-field to the table, and now I get the error `SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input`- Why is that?

The PHP Code looks like this:

```
$app->get('/api/releases', function(Request $request, Response $response) {
$sql = "SELECT * FROM albums";

try{
    $db = new db();

    $db = $db->connect();

    $stmt = $db->query($sql);
    $releases = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    $db = null;
    echo json_encode($releases);
   } catch(PDOException $e) {
       echo '{"error": {"text": '.$e->getMessage().'}';
     }
});
```

Should the Date be converted to a string first?

Comment: maybe fetch as an array rather than objects?

Comment: first step is to see which string is sent to the client. Try to use the same url in a browser and see the returned string.

Comment: Not related to your current problem, but note that your error message is not valid json, you should use `json_encode()` on an array / object there as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [json parsing error syntax error unexpected end of input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20827372/json-parsing-error-syntax-error-unexpected-end-of-input)

Comment: @GiacomoMasseroniChiaro actually the same url returns nothing BUT when  I add an ID of an entry, lets say /api/releases/10 I get the correct data!?!

Comment: I did not get your point. The code you wrote does not need an ID entry. Anyway post the string you get.

Comment: @GiacomoMasseroniChiaro this is what I get when entering /api/releases/10 in the browser `[{"id":"10","band":"Samael ","album":"Hegemony","album_cover":"","release_date":"2017-10-13"}]`

Comment: But you get the error when you do not pass the ID to the url. Is it right?

Comment: @GiacomoMasseroniChiaro yes, correct

Comment: So I need the string you get when you call the "/api/releases" url

Comment: @GiacomoMasseroniChiaro I get absolutely nothing, just the error `Unexpected end of JSON input`

Comment: are you launching this url in a browser?

Comment: @GiacomoMasseroniChiaro yes I do :-)

Comment: That error is a javascript error, you do not see it in the browser