# Cannot Parse JSON data: SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, parsing, syntax

I'm trying to parse data from jokeAPI to generate random jokes. I use the functions response.on() and JSON.parse(), and I've been getting a 200 statusCode, so I know my code is working, but I keep getting errors.

Here is my code:

```
const express = require("express");
const https = require("https");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));

app.get("/", function(req, res) {
  const url = "https://sv443.net/jokeapi/v2/joke/Any?blacklistFlags=nsfw"
  https.get(url, function(response) {
    console.log(response.statusCode);

    response.on("data", function(data){
      const jokeData = JSON.parse(data);
      console.log(jokeData);
    });

  });
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
});



app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log("Server is running on port 3000.");
});
```

Here is the response I get in Hyper:

```
Server is running on port 3000.
200
undefined:6
    "delivery": "T
                  

SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/Users/aimee/Documents/JokeProject/app.js:16:29)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at IncomingMessage.Readable.read (_stream_readable.js:506:10)
    at flow (_stream_readable.js:1006:34)
    at resume_ (_stream_readable.js:987:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

I've researched the error, tried fixing my code, looked at [similar questions like mine on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20827372/json-parsing-error-syntax-error-unexpected-end-of-input) and [other sites like teamtreehouse.com](https://teamtreehouse.com/community/getting-the-error-syntaxerror-unexpected-end-of-json-inputinstead-of-unhandled-error-event) and [stechies.com](https://www.stechies.com/uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-end-json-input/), tried their recommendations and those of countless others, yet no cigar. Does anyone know how I can fix this?

!!-- Update --!!

After I read the documentation for [ReadableStream](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_streams) and [its data event](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_data), as suggested by [T.J. Crowder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157247/t-j-crowder), I updated my code, as written by [dwosk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4151726/dwosk):

```
app.get("/", function(req, res) {
  const url = "https://sv443.net/jokeapi/v2/joke/Any?blacklistFlags=nsfw"
  https.get(url, function(response) {
    console.log(response.statusCode);
    let body = '';

    response.on("data", function(data){
      body += data;
    });
    response.on("end", function() {
      var resp = JSON.parse(body);
      console.log(resp);
    })

  });
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
});
```

Now my code works, and my data is parsed.

```
Server is running on port 3000.
200
{
  error: false,
  category: 'Programming',
  type: 'single',
  joke: 'If Bill Gates had a dime for every time Windows crashed ... Oh wait, he does.',
  flags: {
    nsfw: false,
    religious: false,
    political: false,
    racist: false,
    sexist: false
  },
  id: 22,
  lang: 'en'
}
```

It helped to learn about ReadableStream and its data event, and, after I learned that the data callback is not the entire body, I managed to get the complete JSON text by appending the new data to a string, thus enabling me to parse the data.

Answer (score 2):

The `data` event gives you a **chunk** of data, not all of it. See the documentation for [ReadableStream](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_streams) and its [`data` event](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_data).

You don't know the data is complete until the [`end` event](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_end). Here's an example from the `end` event documentation showing how this works:

> ```js
> const readable = getReadableStreamSomehow();
> readable.on('data', (chunk) => {
>   console.log(`Received ${chunk.length} bytes of data.`);
> });
> readable.on('end', () => {
>   console.log('There will be no more data.');
> });
> ```

Or this example from the [`http.get` documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_get_options_callback) (which the `https.get` documentation links to):

> ```js
> let rawData = '';
> res.on('data', (chunk) => { rawData += chunk; });
> res.on('end', () => {
>   try {
>     const parsedData = JSON.parse(rawData);
>     console.log(parsedData);
>   } catch (e) {
>     console.error(e.message);
>   }
> });
> ```

Note that that assumes an encoding has been provided so the chunks are strings, not `Buffer` instances.

Answer (score 1):

The argument passed to the `data` callback is not the entire body. Try the following:

```
  const url = "https://sv443.net/jokeapi/v2/joke/Any?blacklistFlags=nsfw"
  https.get(url, function(response) {
    console.log(response.statusCode);
    let body = '';

    response.on("data", function(data){
      body += data;
    });

    response.on("end", function() {
      var res = JSON.parse(body);
      console.log(res); // prints your api response
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

The `data` event fires every time some data comes in.

This is really useful when you are streaming large amounts of data as you can deal with it chunk by chunk as it comes in.

You **cannot** parse JSON (at least not with a standard JSON parser) incrementally. You need the **complete** JSON text or you will get, as you have discovered, an exception.

Each time `data` fires, **append the new data to a string**.

When the `end` event fires, **then** parse that string as JSON.

---

You might want to use a library which takes care of collecting all the data together for you, possibly even one that has built-in tools for handling JSON. e.g. `node-fetch` or `axios`.